# Get assoc array from JSON string via JQuery.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I call a PHP script via Ajax. The PHP function transfers an associative array which is encoded by `json_encode()` once.

**JavaScript code**

```
var load_institute = $.post("../libraries/load_content.php", {
    funct: "getInstituteInformation",
    ins_name: "Institut für Informatik",
    ins_city: "Kiel"
}, "json");
load_institute.done(function(data) {
    console.log("Data: "+data);
    console.log("Type: "+typeof data);
    console.log("Faculty: "+data['ins_faculty']); // <-- this is how I need it.
}, "json");
```

The function call returns a valid JSON string.

**Console output**

```
[18:15:27.953] "Data: ﻿{"ins_name":"Institut f\u00fcr Informatik","ins_faculty":"Technische Fakult\u00e4t","ins_street":"HRSl","ins_number":"42","ins_postal_code":"24118","ins_city":"Kiel"}"
[18:15:27.953] "Type: string"
[18:15:27.954] "Faculty: undefined"
```

Why is it still a string? Shouldn't the "json"-dataType attribute already parse it back to normal? I tried it with `.parseJSON()`. Of course a syntax error occurs.
But when I insert the returned JSON string directly into the `.parseJSON()` function, it works fine.

I also already tried these:

1. Using an enumerated array instead of associative. No luck.
2. Adding single/double quotes to the sides of the string and parsing it again. No luck.
3. Using `.ajax()` instead of `.post()`. No change.

What am I missing here? In my view, the dataType declaration of the `JQuery.post()` function should suffice to parse the JSON string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sending a correct header in your PHP script ? Because JQuery will not parse JSON if the data header response is plain text.

Comment: I don't know much about headers. I can assure you that I don't change anything about it. The console displays the Request-Header and the Response-Header. Both seem fine to me. The only thing that might be strange is that the Content-Type for the Response-Header says "text/html".
Manually changing the header within the PHP script to "application/json" causes the `.post()` function to fail.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved. I declared the header to "application/json" and used `ob_clean();` and `flush();` after that. Now it works!